# What is the meaning of 'serialization.format' property of a table in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

When I execute `describe formatted table_name`, then I get detailed description of the table `table_name`.

I am interested in two properties of the table as below:

1. `field.delim`
2. `serialization.format`

   `field.delim` is the field delimiter character in file between two column fields of the table.

But what is the meaning of `serialization.format` field of the table properties?

Comment: Same question here. Looks like 1 is a common value for serialization.format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two properties of hive table:

`field.delim` is the field delimiter character in file between two column fields of the table.

where as `serialization.format` is the field delimiter character in file between two column fields of the table **when the file is serialized** .